# GPO best practices : Security-Group Filtering Versus OU

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, best-practices

Good afternoon everyone,

I'm quite new to Active Directory stuff. After upgraded Functional level of our AD from 2003 to 2008 R2 (I need it to put fine-grained password policy), I then start to reorganized my OUs.
I keep in mind that a good OU organization facilitate application of GPO (and maybe GPP).But in the end, it feels more natural for me to use Security-group filtering (from Scope tab) to apply my policies, instead of direct OU.

Do you think it is a good practice or should I stick to OU ?

We are a small organisation with 20 users and 30-35 computers. So, we got a simple OU tree, but more subtle split with security-groups.

The OU tree doesn't contain any objects except at the bottom level. Each bottom level OU contains Computers,Users, and of course security groups. These security groups contains Users & Computers of the same OU.

Thanks for your advices,
Olivier

Comment: The principles of KISS could never apply more then this situation. I try to use ou based gpo's 1st and if somebody puts a gun to my head I'll using filtering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Benefits to using an OU-based GPO layout

- Easier to immediately see the effected set of objects
- Less overhead involved than managing additional security groups
- Less replication to other DCs and smaller user tokens, since you don't need a bunch of extra security groups (this probably doesn't matter much to a smaller infrastructure like you describe)
- In most organizations, almost all policies can apply at an OU level in a well designed AD
- Easier delegation

### Benefits to using a scope-based GPO layout

- More flexible
- Solves the `where should I put this object?` problem that comes up for employees that might "straddle" departments
- You can delegate the ability to add members to groups, which will allow helpdesk staffers to manage what policies apply where without giving access to changing GPOs

---

In reality, most organizations that I've dealt with take a hybrid approach. A GPO that can be applied based on OU typically is assigned to an OU and anything that "crosses" OUs or needs to be filtered to a subset of an OU uses security filtering or item-level targeting.

In fact, I actually just deployed a single GPO to map 50 printers to various departments and it was linked at the domain level and uses item-level targeting - yet almost all of the other GPOs that we have are linked to an OU with the default security filters.

TL;DR - do what makes sense for your organization.

Comment: This, basically. There's no overall right or wrong - just which one is easier to manage for each individual GPO.

Comment: Thanks for this clear comparison. As you suggest in the end, I will probably manage to apply GPO per OU, and for some of them, apply security filtering through scope.
In addition, I used a GPO made of several GPP for mounting drive. Each gpp is item-level targeting based on security-groups. The GPO is applied at the top OU (called "Office"). This way, I just got one policy to maintan for the whole mounted drives :)

Comment: I'm saying that you should evaluate each GPO based on where/how it needs to apply and make a decision that works for you. What *most* organizations do is default to an OU-based application and dip into filtering if that doesn't meet their needs - but again, it relies on a lot of variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think it all depends on complexity of the environment you are trying to configure with Group Policy. Keeping in mind that an object can be in only a single OU where as an object could be in more that one security group. In simple environments (like your seems to be) I would suggest keeping your policies and the application of those policies simple as well.